# Docker-Compose: permission denied / no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

docker-compose and linux newbie here.
I set up my first docker-compose container and get some errors in my docker logs, which I would like to fix:

```
failed to setup application, mkdir /mnt/vg1/myapp/: permission denied can't make directory /mnt/vg1/myapp
```

so I double-checked the directory permissions, which look fine to me:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser docker  4096 Jan 22 20:54 myapp/
```

(I also tried chmod 777, which didn't solve the errors)

Then I checked, how to specify a user for running `docker-compose up`. I added the `user:`-line to my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
    myapp:
        build: .
        image: myuser/myapp:latest
        container_name: "myapp"
        hostname: "myapp"
        user: "myuser"
        restart: always
...
```

Now things got worse: I cannot recreate my docker container.

```
myuser@myhost:/opt/mydocker$ docker-compose up -d
Removing myapp
Recreating 55419e7048cc_myapp ... error

ERROR: for 55419e7048cc_myapp  Cannot start service myapp: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file

ERROR: for myapp Cannot start service myapp: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

So I checked `/etc/passwd`:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
...
myuser:x:1001:1001:My Admin User,,,:/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

Seems fine for me. So I'm running out of ideas, how to fix this error. :/

Any ideas, what I might be missing?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `volumes:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file; is the `myapp` directory name mentioned anywhere in your setup?  `user:` specifies a user name or ID inside the container, using the _container's_ `/etc/passwd` file, and it's slightly unusual to need it (images often will specify their own `USER`, and you only typically need to override it to get correct permissions to access bind-mounted storage).

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your kind help. Yes, I've specified
`volumes:
   - /mnt/vg1/myapp:/srv/var`

in my `docker-compose.yml` file. I also use `working_dir: /mnt/vg1/myapp` and I have some custom environment variables which also point to the myapp directory, such as `environment:
   - BACKUP_PATH=/mnt/vg1/myapp/backup`
If `user:` is unusual, I will remove it, but then I still have the `permission denied` issue to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today and ran across this thread, which lead me to a solution.

The problem in my case was I was specifying a user that existed in the host OS and NOT the guest OS.  When you specify a "user" in the docker-compose.yml, that controls the user the docker processes are running as inside and outside the container.

For my use case I wanted the file permissions to match (and not be root), so I created a user in the container with the same ID as the outside.  If the goal is to make the files created by the container appear as the same user, you'll need the user "id" to match.

Hope this helps someone else.